# What is called as Ephemeral state and App state in Flutter Application?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to know about the difference between Ephemeral state and App state in Flutter Application. Is there any easy way of example to grasp it.

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/ephemeral-vs-app

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are 02 types of widgets.

```
    1.StatelessWidget
    2.StatefulWidget
```

1.StatelessWidget - this widget only has a build method.(which returns child widget).

2.StateFulWidget - this widget has s build method (child widget) and **this build method

use state objects as parts of it.**

(This means, In stateful widgets UI = build method + state).[this image shows that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOSnX.png)

### Now i think you will know about stateful widget, its UI=build method(state).

**What is State**

State is a any Data that used by build method as a part of its widget tree.

---

**What is Ephemeral state and App state**

**1- Ephemeral State** -when your state variables are in inside of the Stateful widget ,its known as ephemeral state.

Down below that code shows ephemeral state (here **_counter** variable is the state)

`Note -: ephemeral state is always place inside the *State class*`

```
class Counter extends StatefulWidget {
  

  @override
  _CounterState createState() => _CounterState();
}

class _CounterState extends State<Counter> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _increment() {
    setState(() {
      
      _counter++;

    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: _increment,
          child: Text('Increment'),
        ),
        Text('Count: $_counter'),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

---

**2- App State** - When your state variables are in outside of the Stateful widget, its known as App state. (because that state is used by many widgets)

For managing app state, you have to use state management solution (inherited widget or third party library) . Below code shows how counter value(int) was managed by using Cubit state management libray.

```
class CounterCubit extends Cubit<int> {
  CounterCubit() : super(0);

  void increment() => emit(state + 1);
}
```

---

~  For managing ephemeral state you can only use **setState** method.

~  But for managing app state there are many approaches.Some of them are

```
       1.Inherited Widget (“Flutter’s Monad”)
       2.Scoped model
       3.Provider
       4.Bloc / cubit
       5.Riverpod
       6.Mobx
       7.Binder
       8.Redux
```